# What happens after disconnecting DC powered inductor?

Tags: inductor, physics

Voltage over an inductor is proportional to the *di/dt*.

I want to know what happens if I disconnect an inductor from a DC power suddenly.
After disconnecting no current could pass through it, right?
So the voltage must tends to infinity or make a spark?

Comment: Correct, di/dt would be infinite and therefore V would also be infinite. Or, if a spark is produced di/dt isn't infinite but is sufficient to make the spark voltage.

Comment: So always we disconnect an inductor a spark happens ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> voltage over an inductor is proportional to the di/dt .

Correct. Which also means that the di/dt is proportional to the voltage across the inductor.

> I want to know what happens if I disconnect an inductor from a dc power suddenly. after disconnecting no current could pass through it . right ?

Before 'after disconnecting' we have the 'disconnecting' phase.

If the switch opens slowly, then as its resistance increases a little, the current through this resistance creates a voltage, which starts to ramp down the inductor current. The current may ramp down before the switch arcs. If the switch opens fast enough, current will still be flowing when it's open, and the voltage may rise high enough to induce an arc.

If we have some magic rapidly opening switch, the inductor current will still flow to somewhere. It flows into the stray capacitance of the inductor itself. The maximum voltage this capacitance will reach is given by the energy balance. The 0.5LI<sup>2</sup> of energy originally stored in the inductor will become 0.5CV<sup>2</sup> of energy stored in its capacitance, or an external capacitor, if one has been added to the circuit to limit the voltage rise, just like on the old style points ignition of a car.

> so the voltage must tends to infinity or make a spark ?

There is always some stray capacitance, so it will never reach infinity. But it can get high enough to be embarassing, or to arc across switch contacts, or to break down semiconductor devices connected to it.

Answer (score 3):

It is called Flyback as current raises voltage with impedance change so snubbers or clamps are used to suppress, otherwise, air gap burns contacts eventually.

But even a vacuum has dielectric capacitance so the result is ringing and not just a DC exponential rise to infinity. It starts with an exponential pulse but ends with ringing as it decays So rise time is also limited by dv/dt=I/C of smallcap between wires or Cout of FET.

[HERE](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjATCCsB0AMinOWApgWgOwgCwE5YA2ADiwl10SPzHxPmhnhjwGYAoAJxAhJN7wBfYRRAswHAO4g2JXLzEjFC%20BwDGvfoOHawkceExgW0CPAR02WNhDZt8jjgBtZ8kAzcKwWIobCWIBgW1FhguGz6EBBYWNBy8RwAbni4ogqUAvh%20LCxU4FC54rDQ3F7gvuXRqoocYGS8%20Z4ULNX%20SOAoyOByWLmW0o0szdqeajItKlrp4nXQ%20FVimVP9iGCdXUgcAEp4YH6TuPu85His5qxFFg7RHADm01PKENA5g8qecgpj76OtegZxuVPMsfjJltlUgJmu8mq0xD8qGw8J8oEQhAUBBJoAB9aCQHHwHG4aDwIi4kJrQmwepEGgkeoQfBYfBpNmEnEQHFgXGcAAOU08dCgQrOkiRKJARG8lUgWKleIJRMg0GguG5EVssAZtCwaX2PPw1KQYBxbE5OKIZo4AA9FDA-GwIjAFt4FAAVACGAGs0ABnAA6foAfEGwABXQN%20gAuAHsgwBLWMAOwTAC80EHowALNDJoMAHiD2djzgAJrGAGaVoPqcNcLh56NZ%20N%20gDyADEOxxY7IpQocLgiCZiibR2t-OAiLA2PiiOQyfUwkdSr20QOtPPkZT4Osd%20sDzBLPESVQhPN4A4e1L%20yAcJAmViEBP97xwLIEHZ8GqeTzcBA6Q4OQ31WVBx13XcQAAYU9PlPXUBNo09ZN1DQICBG3UcD0CABJZMy3DdQkJQtDgKKA9IO2f0ExjZDUPQm8oBMRANg6AAhRsfQrKR8z9JJSyQu5Mz9MBvQANRbMNEHEhiRyYdZHBAAARcNowATyDKC1PUZxhLAAA-RwAFIOCAA) you may simulate your own circuit. But beware Scope sampling rate affects peak voltage if rise time < 10% of sample time. ... >Options>other options

I used an SPST switch with timer and variable duty to 1H relay coil which if the coil was series connected to its NC contacts makes a 200 Hz oscillator and burns out contacts in a few minutes. You can try that at home. Auto Relay with 12V battery and NC SPDT contact in series with the coil. Then you get continuous pulsed sparks on contacts.

Power, current and voltage on parts are shown in scope. ***Sliders*** are like pots to component values you may add or change on the right side.

You choose whatever you want to simulate, but make it accurate with some ESR and ESL 10nH/cm if you want true physics response.

[image]

Comment: If you put a series R with contacts to prevent burning in a large loop, this will jam any radio phone nearby with lightning noise at rep rate